# I'm getting an Atribute Error in the following Question, can someone help me to figure out the problem

Tags: python, python-re

```
import re
phonenumregex=re.compile(r'ddd-ddd-dddd')
mo=phonenumregex.search("My number is 415-555-4242")
print("Phone Number found: " + mo.group())
 #it gives me this error.



AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I gave the format as ddd-ddd-dddd in raw string. and was expecting to get the number 415-555-4242 in return

Answer (score 0):

Your regec should be correct, `\d` not `d`

```py
import re
# phonenumregex=re.compile(r'\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d')
phonenumregex=re.compile(r'\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}')
mo=phonenumregex.search("My number is 415-555-4242")
print("Phone Number found: " + mo.group())
```